# Set-GPPermission correctly in a script

Tags: powershell, gpo

I started to write a script for my domain but not sure how to finish it.
I got a GPO to turn off Windows firewall without an option to turn it on for endpoint computers in the domain.
I want the new computers to be added to this GPO with the permission "deny all" I'm just not sure how to finish it, this is what I've got so far:

```
$Limit=(Get-Date).AddDays(-7)

$NewPC=Get-ADComputer -Filter {whenCreated -gt $limit} -Properties whenCreated

$NewPC | ForEach-Object Set-GPPermission -Name <GPO_Name> -TargetType Group -PermissionLevel PermissionLevel
```

the two 1st lines just to get the list of the computers which is working well, but I've some kind of trouble in the last line, actually getting the computers into the GPO and to set the permissions right, I tried a few methods but I can't get to work, what am I doing wrong here?

Comment: If your `TargetType` is `Group` then you should add the computers first to said `Security Group` and then add the group to the GPO scope.

Comment: I want to avoid a group for computers and just at all the computers that the script finds in the 2 line above.

Answer (score 0):

After several tries, I managed to figure out a solution to make it work, just keep in mind that, In my environment the PC's are redirected to a different location from the Computer container to an OU and and the principle name is no longer in use so I used the name only.

```
$NewPC | ForEach-Object {Set-GPPermission -Name <GPO> -TargetType Computer -TargetName $NewPC -PermissionLevel GpoApply}
```

Comment: This looks like it grants "apply" permissions - not a "deny all" permission as mentioned in the question.